# how to access my temporary second web site by using URL (or IP) of my primary web site

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP .NET web app site (ie. www.first.com).
I also have a temporary 2nd ASP .NET web app project.
I want to access 2ND site from the Internet by using somehow the URL of the 1ST web site.

How do I set up IIS to do this?

For example, can I have "www.first.com/second" browse the default.aspx of the 2ND web app project?

Host is Windows Server 2016 Pro on my Azure VM.

Comment: did you consider using url rewriting ? [url-rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

How about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/virtual-directory-setup-instructions

In this case your second app become another app under the main one.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use add nested application in your primary application. You could firstly publish your application to the Azure VM's disk. Then you could use IIS's managment console to add the nested application as below：

More details, you could refer to below steps:

1.Open the IIS management console and right click your primary application.

[image]

2.Select application or virtual directory and select the web application physical path.

[image]

Result:

[image]